# Wordpress displaying all posts from a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I am pretty new to wordpress and I made a custom post type 'projecten' and now I would like to display all posts from this type on a page I created.

I made a page template everything is fine and created 1 post.
This is what my page template looks like.

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Projecten Template
*/

$projecten = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'project'));
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
 <div class='full parallax' style='background-image: url(images/@stock/portfolio-header-bg.jpg); color: #fff;'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='twelve columns'>
        <div class='big mod modSectionHeader'>
          <div class='special-title centered-text'>
            <h2 style='color: #fff'>
              <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <h3 class='centered-text' style='color: #fff'><?php the_field('field_56d983a5a4788'); ?></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='four spacing'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='mod modGallery'>
      <?php if ( $projecten->have_posts()): ?>
       <?php while ( $projecten->have_posts()): the_post(): ?>
        <ul class='gallery large-block-grid-4 medium-block-grid-3 small-block-grid-2'>
          <li class='graphic-design'>
            <a href='portfolio-item.html'>
              <img width="400" height="400" alt="" src="" />
              <div class='overlay' >
                <div class='thumb-info'>
                  <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                  <p>hey</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
     </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

It looks okay to me but unfortunately it's not working :(

Comment: Have you tried removing wp_reset_postdata();

Comment: It works when I do that but isn't bad practice to not use wp_reset_postdata();?

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Comment: You said your CPT was "projecten" but you're using `'post_type' => 'project'`

Answer (score 0):

This is an edit of your code which I think will help you. You missed the "en" of the "projecten" within the query.

I also wrapped the loop around the *li* tag rather than the *ul* tag along with a few other tweaks.

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Projecten Template
*/

$projecten = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'projecten'));
?>
<div class='full parallax' style='background-image: url(<?php  bloginfo('template_url');?>/stock/portfolio-header-bg.jpg); color: #fff;'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='twelve columns'>
            <div class='big mod modSectionHeader'>
                <div class='special-title centered-text'>
                    <h2 style='color: #fff'><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                </div>
                <h3 class='centered-text' style='color: #fff'><?php the_field('field_56d983a5a4788'); ?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='four spacing'></div>
</div>
<div class='mod modGallery'>
    <?php if ( $projecten>have_posts() ) { ?>
    <ul class='gallery large-block-grid-4 medium-block-grid-3 small-block-grid-2'>
        <?php while ( $projecten->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <li class='graphic-design'>
            <a href='portfolio-item.html'>
                <img width="400" height="400" alt="" src="" />
                <div class='overlay' >
                    <div class='thumb-info'>
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <p>hey</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It works thanks a lot mate! I have a little question maybe you can help me out. I need images to be links see the <a href> how can I inject the right link of the post? And I need to make a single-project.php template too I guess? I have no idea how that works :p

Comment: Okay the image tag is <?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/stock/portfolio-header-bg.jpg

Comment: I've fixed the image the only ptoblem I have is injecting the correct url in the a href

Answer (score 0):

remove wp_reset_postdata(); its will come after closing of loop.
you have forget this

```
$projecten = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'project'));
while ($projecten->have_posts()) : $projecten->the_post();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Projecten Template
*/

$projecten = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'project'));
?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
 <div class='full parallax' style='background-image: url(images/@stock/portfolio-header-bg.jpg); color: #fff;'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='twelve columns'>
        <div class='big mod modSectionHeader'>
          <div class='special-title centered-text'>
            <h2 style='color: #fff'>
              <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <h3 class='centered-text' style='color: #fff'><?php the_field('field_56d983a5a4788'); ?></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='four spacing'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='mod modGallery'>
      <?php if ( $projecten->have_posts()): ?>
       <?php while ( $projecten->have_posts()): the_post(): ?>
        <ul class='gallery large-block-grid-4 medium-block-grid-3 small-block-grid-2'>
          <li class='graphic-design'>
            <a href='portfolio-item.html'>
              <img width="400" height="400" alt="" src="" />
              <div class='overlay' >
                <div class='thumb-info'>
                  <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                  <p>hey</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
     </div>
    <?php endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

and get the the featured image as below by passing the post_id

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
```

Create your single page as single-.php and you will get all the related things in the page related to that particular page.

For reference you can check the single.php in twentyfifteent theme